# Refactoring rails fat controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refactoring

How can I refactor the following controller fetch action, also how to use local
 variable(`website not @website`, local because it doesn't have a view) in fetch action
 and start_fetching method

```
def fetch    
      @website = Website.find(params[:website_id])
      retun redirect_to :back, :alert => t('crawl_counter_error') if @website.fetch_counter < 1
      authorize! :update, @website, :message => t("website_authorize_error")
      @website.confirmed? || @website.confirmed_key? ? start_fetching : flash[:error] = t('key_error')
      redirect_to :back
  end

private
def start_fetching
    if @website.working_status
      flash[:error] = t('crawling_in_progress_error')
    else
      @website.start_fetch
      flash[:notice] = t('crawler_success_notice')
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a bit cleaner

```
# controller

def fetch
  website.find(params[:website_id])

  authorize! :update, website, :message => t("website_authorize_error")

  status = website.fetch

  flash[status[:type]] = t(status[:message])
  redirect_to :back
end

# move to model/website.rb

def fetch
  status = nil

  if (fetch_counter < 1)
    status = {:error, 'crawl_counter_error'}
  elsif confirmed? || confirmed_key?
    status = {:error, 'key_error'}
  elsif working_status
    status = {:error, 'crawling_in_progress_error'}
  else
    start_fetch
    status = {:notice, 'crawler_success_notice'}
  end

  status
end
```